# Android ClassCastException with TreeMap comparison

Tags: java, android, compare, treemap

I am trying to compare a double value to another double value inside of a TreeMap object. I am getting the following error at the line where I am comparing myPowerAvg to myMap.get(myMap.get(2)). I'm not sure why I'm getting this error as I'm comparing two doubles (btw, this method is executed within a thread).

```
12-10 22:12:30.524: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1059): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-23
12-10 22:12:30.524: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1059): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String
12-10 22:12:30.524: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at java.lang.Integer.compareTo(Integer.java:36)
12-10 22:12:30.524: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at java.util.TreeMap.cmp(TreeMap.java:1317)
12-10 22:12:30.524: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at java.util.TreeMap.get(TreeMap.java:1282)
12-10 22:12:30.524: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at com.community.HomeActivity.setTopUsers(HomeActivity.java:159)
12-10 22:12:30.524: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at com.community.HomeActivity.access$0(HomeActivity.java:136)
12-10 22:12:30.524: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1059):     at com.community.HomeActivity$4.run(HomeActivity.java:127)
```

code:

```
  if(myPowerAvg < myMap.get(myMap.firstKey())){
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstPlace);     
    }else{
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.firstPlace);
        view.setText("First Place: \n" + myMap.firstKey() + " " + 
            " at " + myMap.get(myMap.firstKey()) );
    }

    if(myPowerAvg < myMap.get(myMap.get(2)) &&  myPowerAvg > myMap.get(myMap.firstKey())){
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondPlace);
        view.setText("Second Place: \n" + AppStatus.mUserName + " " + 
             " at " + myPowerAvg;
    }else{
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondPlace);
        view.setText("Second Place: \n" + myMap.get(2) + " " + " at " + 
             myMap.get(myMap.get(2)));
    }
    if(myPowerAvg < myMap.get(myMap.get(2)) &&  myPowerAvg > myMap.get(myMap.firstKey())){ 
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondPlace);
        view.setText("Second Place: \n" + AppStatus.mUserName + " " + " at " 
             + myPowerAvg);
     }else{
        TextView view = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondPlace);
        view.setText("Second Place: \n" + myMap.get(2) + " " + " at " + 
            myMap.get(myMap.get(2)));
     }
```

Comment: Which line is `HomeActivity.java` line 159? The exception specifically says that you're trying to cast a `String` to an `Integer` (which, obviously, you cannot).

Comment: My guess is that you did not provide type parameters in the declaration of your TreeMap variable. Somehow you are comparing a String where it expects an Integer (or vice versa?) and the compiler isn't catching it. I agree with @MДΓΓБДLL about where to start tracking this down. It would help if you also posted the declarations of your `myMap`.

Comment: Line 159 is the line: if(myPowerAvg < myMap.get(myMap.get(2)) &&  myPowerAvg > myMap.get(myMap.firstKey())). Here's the treemap declaration: TreeMap<String, Double> myMap = new TreeMap<String, Double>();

Comment: What is `myPowerAvg` declared as? Seriously, though, just put a breakpoint at like 159 and see which statement throws the exception.

Comment: It's declared as a double. The first "if" statement works. I wish I could put a breakpoint at line 159. I haven't been able to run the debugger for this particular application since I started it - it's an android widget. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say myMap is a `TreeMap<String, Double>` - but you're calling myMap.get(2).  The param to get should be a string.

Comment: I'm calling myMap.get(myMap.get(2), which gets the double value. The first "if" statement works fine. It's the second "if" statement that's failing.

Comment: I finally figured this out: there were several issues. The issue I reported was resolved based on your answer. First, I was trying to print out the top three users based on the double value. However, since the String value was listed first, the TreeMap was ordering based on the string value. To resolve this issue, I set my TreeMap to be TreeMap<Double, String>. I am now iterating through the map like this: for(Map.Entry<Double,String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
           Double key = entry.getKey();
           String value = entry.getValue();} Thanks for your help!